# How to still return a default value when no record is found

Tags: oracle, plsql

When record is not found I want to return a default value, like `N/A`. I tried `DECODE` and `NVL` and `NVL2` but still get nothing. My actual query is much more complex, just posting a simplified version

```
SELECT DECODE(test_date,NULL,'N/A', test_date) test_date
FROM  Table1
WHERE name = 'Unknown'
```

Comment: Just use `nvl(min(test_date) ,'N/A')`

Comment: that gave me an error "non-numeric character found where numeric was expected"

Comment: Ah, I see: you can't return a string into the column with `date` data type. So you need either to transform `min(test_date)` to string using to_char, or use something else instead of 'N/A'

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is that when no rows are found, nothing is shown. To work around that, you could the following: UNION the original select with another select that returns something if the original select has no rows. On the emp table that would be something like this (there is no user "xKING"):

```
SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE ename = 'xKING'
UNION 
SELECT 'N/A' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE ename = 'xKING')
;
```

Functions like `NVL` and `DECODE` tranform the result columns - if there is no result they cannot be used.